# Formatting a Title of a Book within a Book

Tags: titles, italics, citation, book-title

How do I refer to a book-in-a-book?

Which of the following is correct? (as my own writing)

> Monte Becket is famous for *Martin Blight.*
>
> Monte Becket is famous for "Martin Blight."
>
> Monte Becket is famous for *"Martin Blight."*

Comment: This is the general referenciest thing ever. http://www.easybib.com/reference/guide/mla/book

Comment: Your link doesn't quite cover the OP's request. If he is writing a paper or an essay then I would agree that the format suggested is ideal. But in this instance the example sentence seems to suggest a more informal, and less academic approach.

Answer (score 1):

When writing the name of a book or a film, it's usually set in italics. The fact that you yourself are writing a book, or that the name is fictional, makes no difference to the name of the book you are quoting. I could write in an answer on ELU

> Charles Dickens is famous for *Little Dorrit*,

and it's exactly analogous to what you are doing in your book.

Just set it in italics.